# LUNs disappear after rebooting the ESX/ESXi host

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vcenter, lun

A single LUN among from a group disappeared following the ESXI host restart. Neither the host nor the Vcenter can see it.
I have four virtual machines on the LUN  hiden now showing just unknown from VCenter.

Although strange  I see the LUN  available from the list you get when you try to ADD datastore from configuration ==> storage ==> Add Datastore.

I really need to mount the lun without formating since i have those four servers on it.

As an alternative being able to copy the files will do.

thanks

Comment: I have a LUN. I'm having a problem with it. I'm not going to tell you anything about it like where it resides and how I connect to it but I'm going to ask you to help me fix it.